# Tensorflow 1.2.1 :AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'random'

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.6

I have installed tensorflow 1.2.1 and whenever i try to run

`c=tf.random.normal(shape=(3,4),dtype=tf.float32)`

I get the error  `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'random'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
c = tf.random_normal(shape=(3,4),dtype=tf.float32))
```

See the full list of available APIs [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/r1.2/site/en/api_docs/python/index.md)

See the usage [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/r1.2/site/en/api_docs/python/tf/random_normal.md)